# Finding threshold intersection in a D3 chart

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js

I have created a simple line chart using (the excellent) D3. It has a threshold value represented as a horizontal red line. What I would like to do is calculate the positions where the value line intersects the threshold line, like so:

[image: line chart with threshold]

I can get pretty close because I have access to the data array, but I need to be very accurate and for it to work at all scales. If anyone can help I would be extremely grateful. Many thanks.

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/wxt325pL/1/)

```
<div id="chart"></div>


path.line { stroke-width: 2; fill: none; }

var data = [{
    "time": "2014-02-25T19:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.08"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-25T21:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.51"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-25T23:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.14"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-26T01:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.79"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-26T03:00:00Z",
    "temp": "41.17"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-26T05:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.39"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-26T07:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.49"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-26T09:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.29"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-26T11:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.90"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-26T13:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.66"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-26T15:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.01"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-26T17:00:00Z",
    "temp": "37.91"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-26T19:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.64"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-26T21:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.21"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-26T23:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.60"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-27T01:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.13"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-27T03:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.51"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-27T05:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.78"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-27T07:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.54"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-27T09:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.29"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-27T11:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.24"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-27T13:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.00"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-27T15:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.01"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-27T17:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.96"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-27T19:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.20"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-27T21:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.14"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-27T23:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.71"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-28T01:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.88"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-28T03:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.98"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-28T05:00:00Z",
    "temp": "41.05"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-28T07:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.60"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-28T09:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.47"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-28T11:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.39"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-28T13:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.44"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-28T15:00:00Z",
    "temp": "37.58"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-28T17:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.26"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-28T19:00:00Z",
    "temp": "37.83"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-28T21:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.26"
}, {
    "time": "2014-02-28T23:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.25"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-01T01:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.60"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-01T03:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.09"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-01T05:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.92"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-01T07:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.67"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-01T09:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.73"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-01T11:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.93"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-01T13:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.90"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-01T15:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.82"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-01T17:00:00Z",
    "temp": "37.47"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-01T19:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.30"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-01T21:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.17"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-01T23:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.87"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-02T01:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.01"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-02T03:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.31"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-02T05:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.31"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-02T07:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.78"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-02T09:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.32"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-02T11:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.48"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-02T13:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.94"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-02T15:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.42"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-02T17:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.41"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-02T19:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.56"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-02T21:00:00Z",
    "temp": "36.89"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-02T23:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.53"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-03T01:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.97"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-03T03:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.58"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-03T05:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.17"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-03T07:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.50"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-03T09:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.47"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-03T11:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.28"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-03T13:00:00Z",
    "temp": "37.48"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-03T15:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.13"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-03T17:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.17"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-03T19:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.27"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-03T21:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.65"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-03T23:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.78"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-04T01:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.62"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-04T03:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.49"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-04T05:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.65"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-04T07:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.07"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-04T09:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.72"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-04T11:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.46"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-04T13:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.86"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-04T15:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.40"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-04T17:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.39"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-04T19:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.61"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-04T21:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.94"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-04T23:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.43"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-05T01:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.17"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-05T03:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.81"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-05T05:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.68"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-05T07:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.80"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-05T09:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.38"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-05T11:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.05"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-05T13:00:00Z",
    "temp": "37.91"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-05T15:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.28"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-05T17:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.72"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-05T19:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.84"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-05T21:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.74"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-05T23:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.63"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-06T01:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.66"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-06T03:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.71"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-06T05:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.67"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-06T07:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.93"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-06T09:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.48"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-06T11:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.54"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-06T13:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.54"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-06T15:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.90"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-06T17:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.85"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-06T19:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.37"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-06T21:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.58"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-06T23:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.72"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-07T01:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.40"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-07T03:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.68"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-07T05:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.72"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-07T07:00:00Z",
    "temp": "41.08"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-07T09:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.06"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-07T11:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.39"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-07T13:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.83"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-07T15:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.51"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-07T17:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.21"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-07T19:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.25"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-07T21:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.39"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-07T23:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.54"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-08T01:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.31"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-08T03:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.29"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-08T05:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.94"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-08T07:00:00Z",
    "temp": "41.05"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-08T09:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.82"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-08T11:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.14"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-08T13:00:00Z",
    "temp": "36.90"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-08T15:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.69"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-08T17:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.61"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-08T19:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.97"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-08T21:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.58"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-08T23:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.39"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-09T01:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.85"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-09T03:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.66"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-09T05:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.91"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-09T07:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.83"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-09T09:00:00Z",
    "temp": "37.44"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-09T11:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.01"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-09T13:00:00Z",
    "temp": "37.28"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-09T15:00:00Z",
    "temp": "38.47"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-09T17:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.60"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-09T19:00:00Z",
    "temp": "39.15"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-09T21:00:00Z",
    "temp": "40.64"
}, {
    "time": "2014-03-09T23:00:00Z",
    "temp": "37.76"
}];
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").parse;
data.forEach(function (d) { d.time = parseDate(d.time); });

var chart = d3.select("#chart");

var padding = 40,
    width = 950,
    height = 300,
    xTicks = 10,
    yTicks = 8;

var svg = chart.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + padding * 2)
    .attr("height", height + padding * 2)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + "," + padding + ")");

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(xTicks);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(yTicks);

var valueLine = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function (d) {
    return x(d.time);
})
    .y(function (d) {
    return y(d.temp);
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.time;
}));
y.domain([33, 43]);

var mainLine = svg.append("path").attr({
    "class": "line",
    stroke: "steelblue",
    d: valueLine(data)
});

var threshold = 40.5;
svg.append("line").attr("stroke", "#F00").attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(threshold)).attr("x2", width).attr("y2", y(threshold)).attr("class", "line");
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798566/d3-line-path-intersection) may help.

Comment: You can use the method [`getPointAtLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement) of the SVG path element. The following gist may be useful http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/3824661

Comment: Are you aware that the line you are plotting isn't running through your data points? You can see it by adding this code.

    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("cx",function(d){return x(d.time);})
        .attr("cy",function(d){return y(d.temp);})
        .attr("r",1);

This is expected behaviour https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes and Wikipedia. You could use no interpolation (i.e. linear between points) and simple linear interpolation (not requiring D3) to solve this. Pablo's suggestion is good if you want to solve the curve.

Comment: Yes, I know that, thanks Angus. I do want the curves but my about to be posted answer will work with or without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This amended [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxt325pL/2/) does linear interpolation in JS and shows why basis interpolation might not be doing what you expect. I've moved some of the styling to the CSS and also added in circles for your observations with mouseover text so that we can see the details of each observation.

Run this with line 475 both commented out and not:

```
// .interpolate("basis")
```

Towards the end of your dataset, the observations at 5 Mar 05:00 and 23:00 both spike up and then down sharply. The basis interpolated line doesn't cross the threshold, but the observations do. If you solve for the interpolated line, you wouldn't identify those intersections. This might be what you wanted, but it wasn't clear from your question.

The intersects array at the end is where we get the intersect times. It loops through each data pair, checking if they're on different sides of the threshold. If they are, there's a simple linear interpolation calculation to identify the time it crossed, assuming the temperature rose linearly between the observations.

Comment: Is there a way to color the area created by data line and threshold line

Answer (score 0):

Angus' answer is better than mine but I'm posting this in case someone finds it useful. Also, thanks to Pablo for the helpful suggestion.

Add this code to the end:

```
var yLine = y(threshold);
console.log(yLine);
var node = mainLine.node();
var pathLength = node.getTotalLength();
for (var i = 0; i < pathLength; i++) {
    var point = node.getPointAtLength(i);
    console.log(point);
    if(Math.floor(point.y) == yLine) {
        svg.append("circle").attr({cx:point.x, cy:point.y, r:2});
    }
}
```

And this to the CSS:

```
circle {
    fill: green;
}
```

Or open this revised [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxt325pL/4/)